# Maven Tomcat plugin with multiple sub-module WARs

Tags: maven, cas, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a parent pom:

```
<project>

<properties>
  <global.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</global.version>
  <cas.version>4.0.0</cas.version>
</properties>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uk.co.g4me.cas</groupId>
  <artifactId>cas-maven-overlay</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${global.version}</version>

<build>

<plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <port>8080</port>
      <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
      <keystoreFile>${user.home}/.keystore</keystoreFile>
      <keystorePass>changeit</keystorePass>
      <webapps> 
        <webapp> 
          <groupId>uk.co.g4me.cas</groupId> 
          <artifactId>cas-server</artifactId> 
          <version>${global.version}</version> 
          <type>war</type>    
          <asWebapp>true</asWebapp> 
        </webapp>
        <webapp> 
          <groupId>uk.co.g4me.cas</groupId> 
          <artifactId>cas-services</artifactId> 
          <version>${global.version}</version> 
          <type>war</type>    
          <asWebapp>true</asWebapp> 
        </webapp>
      </webapps>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

</plugins>  

</build>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>ja-sig</id>
    <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<modules>
  <module>cas-services</module>
  <module>cas-server</module>
</modules> 

</project>
```

And two sub module poms:

cas-services:

```
<project>

  <parent>
    <groupId>uk.co.g4me.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-maven-overlay</artifactId>
    <version>${global.version}</version>
  </parent>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>cas-services</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
      <artifactId>cas-management-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${cas.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

cas-server:

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <groupId>uk.co.g4me.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-maven-overlay</artifactId>
    <version>${global.version}</version>
  </parent>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>cas-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
      <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${cas.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Running things as they are results in a build failure:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) 
on project cas-services: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run 
failed: addChild:  Child name '/cas-services' is not unique
```

This error is fairly self explainatory, clearly tomcat is compiling the submodule and including the classes for deployment.

So is there anything glaringly wrong with what i'm trying to do here?

I've tried a number of different configurations but just can't get these to play nicely together.

All works well if I remove the modules element. However this is less than ideal as there will eventually be many more modules added and I'd like to clean and install them all from the parent.

I also suspect this could be solved with setting a profile but I think I'd like to understand the issue before working around it.

Any insights appreciated.